# HQL / Postgres : EXTRACT(dow from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) with a parameter

Tags: postgresql, hql

I am trying to implement following query to retrieve users that need to be alerted weekly and send alerts on Monday.
Following query works :

```
String sql = "SELECT user_id FROM table"
        + " WHERE alert_interval = 7 AND EXTRACT(dow from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = 1))";
```

But if I want to pass a parameter to EXTRACT(dow from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) like this :

```
String sql = "SELECT user_id FROM table"
            + " WHERE alert_interval = 7 AND EXTRACT(dow from : currentTs) = 1))";
    
        var args = new MapSqlParameterSource("currentTs", currentTs);
    
        jdbcOperations.query(sql, args, (ResultSet rs) -> ...);
```

I am getting following error :

```
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, unknown) is not unique
  Hint: Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Not sure how I can pass a parameter to EXTRACT(dow from ...) ?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Th error message is telling you the problem: `select EXTRACT(dow from '01/23/2023'); ERROR:  function pg_catalog.extract(unknown, unknown) is not unique` vs `select EXTRACT(dow from '01/23/2023'::date); 1`.  `currentTs` is not being seen as a `date`. You don't show how the value was assigned to it but I'm guessing not as a `date`.

Comment: `currentTs` is a (java.sql) Timestamp.
`currentTs = Timestamp.from(inputZonedDateTime.toInstant());`

Comment: `EXTRACT(dow FROM :currentTs::date)`made it work

Comment: Hmm, then something in your stack is not preserving the data type and is passing the parameter as a string.